# How to style the divider in the AntD Card actions panel?

Tags: antd

[Card Actions Divider Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXfTY.png)

I am using `AntD Card` componenent. I have tried to style the divider in the actions panel (shown in the picture) I have tried to set the `css` likeso:

```
.ant-card-actions {
 // other code
    .ant-divider {
    background: white !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using inline css

```
<Divider
    type="vertical"
    style={{ borderLeft: '2px solid white', height: '30px' }}
  />
```

Or

You can customize the css class

```
.ant-divider-vertical {
   height: 20px;
   border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

Result: Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.ant-card .ant-card-actions>li:not(:last-child) {
    border-inline-end: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

You can try this; I had the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).